# When I search on Podcasts on iPad Pro, found podcasts are in German not English

Tags: ipad, podcasts, ipados

I bought the iPad in German and I made my country Germany back then. Now when I search on Podcasts, all podcasts shown are in German language. How to fix that? I want to see Podcasts that are in English too.

I have iPadOS 15.0.2 betta.

I bought my iPad in Austria. At first I put my language German, and my country Austria. But now I have changed my default language to English, and my country to United States. I also changed the preferred language in podcast settings.

Comment: idk if this will help anyone, but I could not find 'search by language', then realized I can just search with the foreign language itself, eg. drop 旅行 into the search bar.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open iTunes on an iPad.
2. Scroll to the bottom and find a setting to **Change Region**; you may need to set up a new payment subscription.
3. Restart the iPad.

Similarly, on an iPhone,

1. Open iTunes.
2. Scroll again to the bottom and find the option to **Change Region**.
3. Restart the iPhone.

Then open Podcasts and all should be well in either case.

Comment: It asked payment information! That is just to change my region! People travel, people relocate. Then why should changing region be such a big deal on Apple?

Answer (score 0):

Search should find podcasts in other languages, no matter what your app setting is set to. You can change the app language in the settings (see below). To change your suggestions in the Browse tab you will most likely have to change your Billing Address as suggested per comment.

---

You can simply select the language in the settings app.

Open the `settings` app, locate the `Podcasts` tab and set your `preferred language`. Simply open the Podcasts app and search in English. Results will now show English podcasts.

[image: How to change the settings]

---

If this does not work, use the Feedback App to report back to Apple that there is a bug, since it is working for me on iPadOS 14.4.

Comment: I just checked. The selected language on Setting-Podcast was English. But podcast search still brings German podcasts.

Comment: Other than restarting the app and/or restarting the iPad there is nothing you can do I guess. Report this to Apple though, since this may very well be a bug in your beta version. You could try to revert to the last non-beta version (14.4) and check if you still experience that problem

Comment: This seem to only change the interface language, not the recommendation. Which country's store you use (and I guess podcast) is determined by the billing address of your payment method.

Comment: The question was about search and not about the browse tab, but you are correct I think. Search should always find english or other language podcast when you search for them

Comment: Arguably good hardware with questionable software assumptions. Personally, that’s how this starts to feel like.